# How do I configure autoformatting in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, code-standards

I dislike how auto format messes up empty cycle body, like:

### Before

```
for (int i = 0; isTest(i); i++);
```

### After

```
for (int i = 0; isTest(i); i++)
    ;
```

How to configure eclipse not to do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why on earth would you want a loop that does nothing?

Comment: That loop might do something. The isTest method can have almost any side effect ;)

Comment: Urgh.  Then it should be a while loop so the "isTest(i)" is in the body.  In my opinion "for" loops should only contain iteration steps between the parenthesis.

Comment: I suggest a custom compiler warning rather than a custom formatting for this special case :-P

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I agree, I'm just saying it's possible

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Windows</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, and in the options table select <kbd>Java</kbd> -> <kbd>Code Style</kbd> -> <kbd>Formatter</kbd>, then configure to your hearts content.

For future reference, in the <kbd>Preferences</kbd> menu you can just type in a search term to find all options for that term - so just going onto the <kbd>Preferences</kbd> menu and typing "format" will show you all options

Comment: & "new lines" -> "empty statements" 
uncheck "Put empty statements on new line"

Comment: This is in the current workspace, not in the Eclipse installation, hence you need to export and import your preferences to have this available in other workspaces.