# Change Format of css Stylesheets in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse

So Eclipse can auto-format my css files under Source->Format, or by hitting Cntl-Shift-F.

When I group selectors for a single rule, eclipse formats it like this:

```css
.planner th,.planner td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I would really like Eclipse to add a space between the selectors to aide readability, like this:

```css
.planner th, .planner td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Is there any way I can configure Eclipse to do this?  I'm running Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392744/how-do-i-configure-autoformatting-in-eclipse

I believe this should solve your problems...

Comment: @will, No, those options are specific to the Java formatter and don't affect CSS formatting.

Comment: Does it not let you select the language you want to format though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) plugin for eclipse has a formatter that's pre-configured according to your needs.

I recommend using it regardless as it ease up the development process a great deal for web developers (all sorts of nifty features like built-in Git integration, code assist for common JavaScript libraries, integrated FTP client, embedded AJAX server [Jaxer], nice themes included, etcetera, etcetera...).

**References:**

- [Aptana Studio download page](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll download the plugin and try it out.

Comment: Does the trick by default, and offers a lot of other coolness for working with css in eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem would be to run a find/replace command like so.

1. Open up File/Replace ( `Ctrl`+`F`) on the CSS file.
2. Find: `,\.`
3. Replace: `, \.`
4. Check the `regular expressions` box.
5. Click `Replace All`.

Alternatively If your want can't be configure through the CSS editor (which seems to be so), then you're going to have to make a plugin for it.

CSS Editor is located here:

```
Preferences > Web > CSS Files > Editor
```

If you're considering making a plugin, then check out the package `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter` for help.

More information here:

- [Eclipse CSS Editor options](http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-305.html)
- [Eclipse Plugin Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html)

Comment: It's admittedly a pretty easy problem to fix in various ways, but I want eclipse to do it for me.  I hope writing a custom plugin isn't the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CSS class macro rule or even a macro, it works great in a text file but not so much the Java editor.

But your utlimate answer is add/change rules in ICSSStyleSheet, there is an explanation here:
http://lab.benstucki.net/flashsac/doc/org/w3c/css/dom/ICSSStyleSheet.html#insertRule() <-- include those brackets.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is, could you please clarify?